# Commit the state of a previous commit again on top of the head commit

Tags: git

We had some changes with a large number of commits that did not work out. We want to keep those in the history, but now we want to get the state of an older commit to be on top of these:

Current:

```
A -> B1 -> B2 -> ... -> Bn
```

Goal:

```
A -> B1 -> B2 -> ... -> Bn -> A
```

The goal is to keep the Bs and that the code looks like when we had A only. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do that is with a restore, these days:

```
git restore --source=A --worktree --staged -- .
git commit -m "Taking it back to how A was"
```

Then you get a history like this:

```
A <- B1 <- B2 <- ... <- Bn <- A'
```

I reversed the arrows because in `git`, children *point* to parents, not the other way around.

Comment: That works too, and it's arguably simpler. You're cheating! ;-D

Comment: I agree, it's much simpler.... it took me a while to get the hang of `git restore` but now that it's in my toolbox (at least the basics), it's quite handy.

Comment: I don't have really adopted it yet I guess, I would have gone for the old-timey `git checkout A -- .`

Comment: The old ways with `checkout; reset --soft; git commit; git branch -f` would do, for sure.... but `restore` avoids all the hassle and having to move the pointer around.

Comment: @eftshift0 why can't I find this (e.g. --worktree) in the documentation at https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_git_commands?

Comment: @Beginner see the [`git restore` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)

Answer (score 2):

The [commit-tree command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree) *might* look slightly convoluted, but your situation is maybe its ideal use-case.

From your branch, starting with a clean working tree, in a single command:
*(`A` has of course to be replaced here by its actual hash or any ref pointing to it)*

```
git reset --hard $(git commit-tree -m "We returned to state A because XYZ" -p $(git rev-parse HEAD) $(git rev-parse A^{tree}))
```

---

Now to make it clearer by looking at it bit by bit:

We use the command signature `git commit-tree [-m <message>] -p <parentCommit> <tree>` where `tree` is the tree ref for the new commit to be created.

`$(git rev-parse A^{tree})` gets the tree object ref from `A`.

`-p $(git rev-parse HEAD)` sets HEAD as the parent commit.

Finally, we send the new commit as an argument to the top-level `git reset --hard` command to make the branch point to the new commit just created.

You now have a new commit on top of your branch, and the state of the files is exactly the same as it was in `A`.

---

As a bonus for those (everyone?) who do *not* want to type (or exactly remember) all this, the "reset-by-commit-tree" alias :

```
git config alias.rbct '!f() { git reset --hard $(git commit-tree -m "(reset-by-commit-tree) Return to $1" -p $(git rev-parse HEAD) $(git rev-parse $1^{tree})); }; f
'

# then, to invoke it, simply
git rbct <commit-to-return-to>
```

Comment: Which ones? Thery're all included in history by ancestry since the new commit is just added on top. History is not rewritten here. Yes, commit-tree feels like black magic :-)

Comment: Oh, disregard my comment.... I jumped to conclusions veeeery early :-D

Comment: Actually, you deserve an apology.... I _thought_ you had messed up on the basics. My bad. :-D

Comment: No offense at all my friend, coming from you it made me seriously pause and reread myself.